# Android "slows down" when screen is off

Tags: android, service

I’m working on an app that posts to the internet every 30 sec. Everything is working fine until the screen goes off. The timer appears to have slowed down. It takes like 5 min to post. I’ve tried acquiring wake-lock and setforegroundactivity but nothing works. Any ideas here?

Its running as a service, I use this for wake-lock:

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

And the example here to set foreground: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

I’ve also tried to check what it can be using the debugger, but everything works fine when the USB is connected.

More detail:
To check with regular intervals I use this:

```
Private void startCheck() {
mCheckHandler.sleep(30000);
}

    private CheckHandler mCheckHandler = new CheckHandler(); 
     private class CheckHandler extends Handler {  
            @Override  
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
                Pservice.this.startCheck();
            }  

            public void sleep(long delayMillis) {  
              this.removeMessages(0);  
              sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);  
            }  
          };
```

I set it to acquire wake lock every time it checks the internet. Now it works fine :) Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: The phone is not in the mood to get it's battery drained? /usefulcomment *(seriously, this is too vague. Be more specific how you do things, illustrate with small code samples - otherwise we can just guess around)*

Comment: the link and the code you given are no where related to your problem. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

When the screen goes off, the device will eventually go into a low power state. This low power state basically means your code will not be executed. The reason it takes 5 minutes is because some other app is waking the device up and then your app gets the chance to run again.

By having the device connected via USB, you are preventing the low power state from ocurring.

It sounds like your wake lock is not actually being acquired or it's being released too soon.

Comment: I set it to acquire wake lock every time it checks the internet. Now it works fine :) Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on any other devices, roms, emulators? Sometimes a simple problem with the way a device manufacture's code can cause issues like that.

What device and rom are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I for one aggressively underclock my android devices when the screen is off.

Also, you mentioned:

> I’ve also tried to check what it can be using the debugger, but everything works fine when the USB is connected.

Try using [ADB Wireless](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adbwireless-%28widget-version%29/siir.es.adbWireless) to debug without being on USB power or just use logging instead.